# How to Organise Live Websocket data into dataframe

Tags: pandas, dataframe, websocket, algorithmic-trading

I have Websocket connection with Kotak Sec Broker for live data,
Building ORB Algo Trading bot

```
try:
    def callback_method(msg):
        print(msg)
               
        #print("Your logic/computation will come here.")
    # subscribe to the streamingAPI
    client.subscribe(input_tokens="96798,39958", callback=callback_method, broadcast_host="https://wstreamer.kotaksecurities.com/feed")
except Exception as e:
    print("Exception when calling StreamingApi->subscribe: %s\n" % e)
```

I have tried various method to organise this data in row column or say Dataframe to process it
further. Pls show me way to do this.

```
WebSocket connection accepted with {'sid': 'OmxNu5RY3xIc04OgCh5z', 'upgrades': [], 'pingInterval': 25000, 'pingTimeout': 5000}
Engine.IO connection established
Sending packet MESSAGE data 0
Received packet MESSAGE data 0
Namespace / is connected
Emitting event "pageload" [/]
Received packet MESSAGE data 2["message","Welcome to StreamerIO (Build: 20200709)."]
Sending packet MESSAGE data 2["pageload",{"inputtoken":"96798,39958"}]
Received event "message" [/]
Received packet MESSAGE data 2["message","Welcome to StreamerIO (Build: 20200709)."]
Received event "message" [/]

Output from spyder call 'get_namespace_view':
Received packet MESSAGE data 2["getdata",["0157101","96798","7051.0000","900","7052.0000","800","7051.0000","7063.0000","7020.0000","7038.9000","7058.0000","7040.0000","-0.0992","20500","37400","159700","6690","112411290000.00","2","05/10/2022 17:26:56","-7.0000","7340.0000","6776.0000"]]
Received event "getdata" [/]

Output from spyder call 'get_namespace_view':
['0157101', '96798', '7051.0000', '900', '7052.0000', '800', '7051.0000', '7063.0000', '7020.0000', '7038.9000', '7058.0000', '7040.0000', '-0.0992', '20500', '37400', '159700', '6690', '112411290000.00', '2', '05/10/2022 17:26:56', '-7.0000', '7340.0000', '6776.0000']
Received packet MESSAGE data 2["getdata",["0157101","96798","7051.0000","500","7052.0000","800","7051.0000","7063.0000","7020.0000","7038.9000","7058.0000","7040.0000","-0.0992","20500","34800","159700","6690","112411290000.00","2","05/10/2022 17:26:56","-7.0000","7340.0000","6776.0000"]]
Received event "getdata" [/]
['0157101', '96798', '7051.0000', '500', '7052.0000', '800', '7051.0000', '7063.0000', '7020.0000', '7038.9000', '7058.0000', '7040.0000', '-0.0992', '20500', '34800', '159700', '6690', '112411290000.00', '2', '05/10/2022 17:26:56', '-7.0000', '7340.0000', '6776.0000']
Received packet MESSAGE data 2["getdata"
```

Answer (score 0):

I guess your websocket response is in JSON. You can create Dataframe from JSON using `pd.normalize_json()`.

```
import pandas as pd
pd.normalize_json(json)
```

If you want to convert dataframe to html table, you can do it by `df.to_html()`.